# Formatting brackets in Eclipse (Control + Shift + f)

Tags: eclipse

When I use the Control + Shift + f it changes

```
public void method 
{
    //stuff
}
```

to

```
public void method {
    //stuff
}
```

I prefer my curly braces the first way. Is there a way to allow it to fix the white spaces and put the curly braces on the next line instead?

Comment: It should be somewhere in the preferences, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code format settings can be found in "Preferences" > "Java" > "Code Style" > "Formatter".

Then press the "Edit" button and select the "Braces" tab.

The settings you apply here will be applied to your code the next time you press CTRL-SHIFT-F